# Classification Tree

Tags: r, tree, classification, data-mining

I have an excel table of customer data per month, and I want to create a tree of classification,to track these data and know the behavior of clients per month

there is an example of what i want in the attached Img [image]

Comment: Great.  Your first step is coming up with a set of predictors or features which describe the behavior of each customer.  This would be necessary for supervised machine learning.

Comment: First, you may need to clarify your classification methodology. Is it a supervised problem (it means you have enough label information) or unsupervised problem. They can be very different.